# Is There Any Further Content on the Starship Enterprise C?

Tags: star-trek, books, star-trek-tng, comics

The Enterprise C gets a brief glimpse to viewers in TNG episode “Yesterday’s Enterprise”, but that’s it.

Is there any additional content out of universe that delves deeper into the history of the ship? (Comics, novels, even just producer or writer mentions)?

In-universe, we all know she was destroyed in the battle of Nirenda III. But what of the time before that? Is that all just a cloud of mystery that we will never know about and thus the “C” is lost to that limited existence?

Comment: I've voted to close as lacking in focus. The Enterprise C has appeared in many (many) books, comics and etc.

Comment: Pretty easy to find info on Memory Beta too

Answer (score 2):

For novels and other non TV or movie materials that give information about the Enterprise-C, see https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-C) (not sure if the page is complete though)